# Steigen von ... auf bzw. sinken um/auf/bis zu

Tags: meaning, preposition, usage

Kann mir jemand die Unterschiede zwischen *»sinken um«*, *»sinken auf«* und *»sinken bis zu«* erklären?

Gibt es so etwas auch für *»steigen«* oder benutzt man hier nur *»steigen von ... auf«*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sinken**

> (1) Die Temperatur sinkt nachts **um** 5 Grad.
>
> (2) Die Temperatur sinkt nachts **auf** 5 Grad.
>
> (3) Die Temperatur sinkt nachts um **bis zu** 5 Grad.

Bedeutung:

(1) Nachts ist es 5 Grad kälter als tags.

(2) Nachts wird eine Minimaltemperatur von 5 Grad erreicht.

(3) Nachts ist es maximal 5 Grad kälter als tags.

**Steigen**

> (1) Die Temperatur steigt tags **um** 5 Grad.
>
> (2) Die Temperatur steigt tags **auf** 5 Grad.
>
> (3) Die Temperatur steigt tags um **bis zu** 5 Grad.

Bedeutung:

(1) Tags ist es 5 Grad wärmer als nachts.

(2) Tags wird eine Maximaltemperatur von 5 Grad erreicht.

(3) Tags ist es maximal 5 Grad wärmer als nachts.

*»sinken auf«* / *»steigen auf«* kann mit einem komplizierterem Konstrukt durch *»sinken bis zu«* / *»steigen bis zu«* ersetzt werden:

> (a) Die Temperatur sinkt nachts **auf** 5 Grad.
>
> (b) Die Temperatur sinkt nachts **bis zu** einem Wert von 5 Grad.
>
> (a) Die Temperatur steigt tags **auf** 5 Grad.
>
> (b) Die Temperatur steigt tags **bis zu** einem Wert von 5 Grad.

Eine Aussage wie *»Die Temperatur sinkt nachts **bis zu** 5 Grad«* ist zweideutig. Es kann *»Die Temperatur sinkt nachts um bis zu 5 Grad«* gemeint sein oder *»Die Temperatur sinkt nachts bis zu einem Wert von 5 Grad«*.

Ebenso zweideutig ist eine Aussage wie *»Die Temperatur steigt tags **bis zu** 5 Grad«*. Es kann *»Die Temperatur steigt tags um bis zu 5 Grad«* gemeint sein oder *»Die Temperatur steigt tags bis zu einem Wert von 5 Grad«*.

**von ... auf** kann man sowohl beim Sinken als auch beim Steigen verwenden:

> - Die Temperatur sinkt **von** 10 **auf** 5 Grad.
> - Die Temperatur steigt **von** 5 **auf** 10 Grad.

Comment: Vielen Dank ...sie haben das super erklärt ....

Comment: aber ist es auch so mit steigen ?

Comment: @MikeAshi: Habe die Antwort aktualisiert.

Answer (score 0):

"Sinken um 20" bedeutet, dass etwas um 20 weniger wird. Benutzt wird etwas für Preise, Prozentsätze, Temperatur, ... 
"Sinken auf 20" bedeutet, dass etwas weniger wird und dabei 20 übrig bleibt, benutzt man für spezielle Kontexte: ein Preis sinkt auf 20€. 
"Sinken bis 20" bedeutet, dass etwas weniger wird und dabei 20 übrig bleibt, für spezielle Kontexte: ein U-Boot sinkt bis zu einer Tiefe von 20 Metern unter dem Meeresspiegel.